# Why doesn’t $F[x]/p(x)$ contain $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

In an existing question and response, there is the statement that the field extension $F[x]/p(x)$ does not strictly speaking contain the field $F$?  Why is that?  The potential reason I can think of is that the elements in the field extension formed from polynomials of degree zero in $x$ are actually not just elements in $F$ but are elements in $F$ plus the ideal generated by $p(x)$?

Comment: Elements of the quotient ring are *equivalence classes* of elements of $F[x]$, not single elements.

Comment: Heck, technically, $F[x]$ might not contain $F,$ if "contains" means "is a subset of," depending on how you defin $F[x].$ But this is a boring technicality. For all our purposes, the ring and the quotient ring contains $F,.$ The problem with using "contains" to mean "has an isomorphic subring" is that the isomorphism is not always uniquely determined.

Comment: Previously given as  answer is given as a comment:  In Lang's book "ALGEBRA" in the chapter on Algebraic extensions and the section titled "Algbraic closure" he outlines, for a given irreducible polynomial over a field k, how to construct an extension field E

where that polynomial has a root. Reading that will be instructive. (The copy I have is the original first edition where it is Prop 7 in page 168).

Comment: There is a canonical morphism $F\to F[x] \to F[x]/(p(x))$ and this is either injective or the zero map (the latter iff (p(x)) = F[x]) because the only ideals in a field are zero or the entire field. So it is sensible to say that $F[x]/(p(x))$ contains $F$ if $p(x)$ does not generate the unit ideal.